# Как снять отметку с определенного слова? markjs

Tags: javascript, markjs

Для выделения слов на странице я использую [markjs](https://markjs.io/)

Хочу снять выделения отметку с определенного слова, для этого есть метод **unmark** но он снимает отметку со всех слов.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: добавь рабочий код, так будет легче помочь

Answer (score 0):

var context = document.querySelector(".context");
var instance = new Mark(context);
instance.unmark(options);

Option element - Will remove only marked elements with this specific element

Option className - Will remove only marked elements with this specific class name